# RpivotTable - slider instead of checkbox

Tags: r, shiny, pivot-table, rpivottable

Is there any option to change checkbox in RPivotTable to Sliders for some of variables?

Thank you.

[image: screenshot - RPivotTable]

Comment: Hi. I'm the author of `rpivotTable`, which is a wrapper of a JS library called `pivottable`. Sadly `pivottable` doesn't use sliders. On the other hand you could filter a dataframe with sliders (if you use shiny) before submitting it to `rpivotTable`. I'm sure it would look quite cool.

Comment: HI, I going to solve the problem this way, thank you.